# How to enable C++0x features in Visual studio? [Initializer Lists support]

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++11

I had some code that I developed on Ubuntu and now I am trying to compile it on Windows 7 (MS VS 2010).

```
vector<float> tmp;
....
tmp = {3.0,4.5,9.4};
```

This gives me syntax error

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
```

Is this because Visual studio doesn't support this feature ? or should I be enabling some switch in the properties. I have the "Platform Toolset" property set to "v100."

Thank you.

Comment: For reference on C++0x support in current compilers, check Apache stdcxx's page: http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport - only GCC 4.4+ has initializer lists.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The C++0x features are enabled by default on the Visual Studio 2010 C++ compiler.  It takes no extra switches for example to use lambdas, `auto`, etc ...  If you're getting that error it's because in all likelyhood it's not supported.

**EDIT**

Based on this MSDN article, initializer lists are not one of the 6 supported features in 2010

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336130.aspx

> the Visual C++ compiler in Visual Studio 2010 enables six C++0x core language features: lambda expressions, the auto keyword, rvalue references, static_assert, nullptr and decltype

Answer (score 16):

Visual Studio 2010 doesn't support initializer lists.
Look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/06/c-0x-core-language-features-in-vc10-the-table.aspx) for the supported C++0x features in Visual Studio 2010

Visual Studio 2012 doesn't support them, too.
You can find he C++11 features that are implemented in Visual Studio 2012 / VS11 [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421825/c11-features-in-visual-studio-2012).

**The first implementation of initializer list is available in the [Visual C++ Compiler November 2012 CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515).**

The first real release of [initializer lists will be in Visual Studio 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/27/what-s-new-for-visual-c-developers-in-vs2013-preview.aspx).

Comment: Too bad that VS2010 doesn't support it.

Answer (score 3):

Even if they were there, this code would not work because it assigns an initializer list, which is not yet a vector, to an existing object named 'tmp'. You can assign to vectors like this:

```
vector<int> tmp = vector<int> {...}; // calls constructor, initializes then assigns
```

or

```
std::initializer_list<int> iniList = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

but not

```
std::vector<int> tmp;
tmp = {...}; // calls assignment operator
```

By the way: the feature is still missing in VS2012.

Comment: As an update, the syntax "tmp = {...}" now compiles in VS2013 & g++ 4.7.1.