# C++11 features in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-c++-2012

A preview version of Visual Studio 2012 (the next version after VS2010) is [now available](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2011/09/14/announcing-visual-studio-11-developer-preview.aspx).

Does anyone know what new C++11 features it supports? (I'm not in a position to try it out at the moment).

Comment: And I'm left disappointed once more. Now to figure out how to use GCC/GDB more fluently...

Comment: GMan: I think their uptake on new features is pretty astonishing, certainly in view of where they're coming from (think VC 6.0 and shudder)... Sure, GCC's support is astonishing, but there are a lot of other places it is lacking too...

Comment: @rubenvn: Just out of curiosity, in what places is GCC lacking?

Comment: GCC is not lacking in support of C++ 11, it is pretty much umatched. VC11 is humorously lacking. It is not even close.

Comment: @HighCommander4: In what places is GCC lacking? Debugging tools.

Comment: @Mehrdad does make a very good point here. I'd love to use everything gcc has, but after years of using the VS debugging tools losing them would set me *way* further back than just missing some new interesting features.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

It's worth noting that Visual Studio 2010 already had quite a bit of early C++11 support. So to summarize what is already linked to in other answers, here is what is new in Visual Studio 11 that was not part of Visual Studio 2010:

- rvalue references to [version 2.1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1138) from 2.0
- lambdas to [version 1.1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2927.pdf) from 1.0.
- decltype to [version 1.1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3276.pdf) from 1.0<sup>(not yet available in developer preview)</sup>
- Improved, but still incomplete, [Alignment](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2341.pdf)
- [completed strongly-typed enums](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2347.pdf)
- [forward declared enums](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2764.pdf)
- [Standard layout and trivial types](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2342.htm)
- [Atomics](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2427.html)
- [Strong compare and exchange](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2748.html)
- [Bi-directional fences](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2752.htm)
- [Data-dependency ordering](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2664.htm)
- [Range-based for loop](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2930.html)

In early November 2012, Microsoft [announced](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/11/02/visual-c-c-11-and-the-future-of-c.aspx) the  [Visual C++ Compiler November 2012 CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515), which adds more C++11 functionality to Visual Studio 2012:

- [uniform initialization](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2477.pdf)
- [initializer lists](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2672.htm)
- [variadic templates](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2555.pdf)
- function template default arguments
- [delegating constructors](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1986.pdf)
- [explicit conversion operators](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2437.pdf)
- [raw strings](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2442.htm)

Comment: That's actually quite disappointing... I was hoping for variadic templates and uniform initialization, which GCC has been supporting for two and half and one and a half years, respectively...

Comment: @High uniform initialization isn't even on their list of features in the spec (doesn't even show up with a "No"). Is there perhaps another name for that?

Comment: I really love my type safe print and printf functions.  I was really hoping that 2011 would finally add variadic templates.  Missing variadics is also effecting `emplace_back` and `make_shared`.  Is there something about cl that makes it particularly hard to implement variadics?

Comment: Herb Sutter said in his second Build session (http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-835T) that they tried to do variadic templates ... tried and tried and they are not done in time for this version. This affected what other things they could do, as well.

Comment: Nice find! He also said in the same talk that we will not have to wait 2-3 years for a version that includes variadic templates - that's encouraging.

Comment: Here is a good comparison of different compilers on C++11. https://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport Good rule: don't use C++11 in GCC and expect it to compile in VS2012