# How to convert visual studio 2010 SP1 solution into visual studio 2012 solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I know they (most project types) are inter-compatible between 2010 SP1 and 2012, and there is no necessity to do conversion, but what if I need it anyway? What if I need my solution to be labeled as Visual Studio 2012 solution? When double clicking the VS2010 solution, version selector automatically opens it with VS2010 (even though I have VS2012 installed now), also icon has a number 10 (instead of number 11) on it.

How to do it??.

Comment: Have you tried opening your 2010 solution in 2012? It should upgrade automatically.

Comment: @jrummell: No; the icon wopn't change.

Comment: That's the key point - I'm opening it in 2012 but it still stays as 2010 solution. No conversion prompt, nothing...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Open it in VS2012, then click File, Save As.

Comment: FYI, this doesn't work for me. There is no Save As displayed under the File menu for me. However, I instead followed the advice [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12406912/5380) and it worked.

Comment: @KentBoogaart This works for me if I first left-click the solution (at the very top of the Solution Explorer) before I do the "Save As"

Comment: @TX_: because its completely un-natural ? I mean seriously, I tried `save all` function and it didn't do the same as `save as`, so wt* micrsoft ?

Comment: @v.oddou: Otherwise, it applies to the active document.

Comment: @SLaks: ehm... I'm befuddled now. Save all applies to active document you say ?

Comment: @v.oddou: I'm talking about Save As.  What are you asking?

Answer (score 4):

Simply open the solution file in a text editor and change the following two lines

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
```

to

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2012
```

Or, you can right click on the solution file, choose property, and change the program you want to use to open the file from Visual Studio Selector to Visual Studio 2012. It will open the solution in VS 2012 regardless the version of the file, which I kind of like.

[image]