# How can you batch upgrade solution files to open in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

This is similar to [How to force a Solution file (SLN) to be opened in Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19513306/60067) but not the same. I have a bunch of .sln files associated with Visual Studio Version Selector. However, they all contain `# Visual Studio 2012` but I would like them to open in Visual Studio 2013 instead. I can open the solution files with the `/upgrade` flag as per [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w15a82ay.aspx). However, it simply says

```
This project/solution does not require migration. It will open without modification.
```

and doesn't change the files, therefore they still open in VS2012. You can explicitly open the solution in Visual Studio 2013 and do a Save As, but this is a very manual process and I have hundreds of solutions. Surely there is a better way than a find/replace in files?

Comment: I haven't found a solution other than doing a find/replace in files with UltraEdit or Notepad++. However, it amazes me that there isn't an easier, more robust way.

Answer (score 0):

You must right click on solution file - > open with - > Choose default program 
and then choose visual studio 2013 and mark checkbox "Use this app for all .sln files"

Comment: I was aware of this approach and it works, but the solution files still specify Visual Studio 2012, which doesn't seem ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this yet but... using the command in the format `devenv "MyProject.sln" /upgrade` you could recurse all the folders and upgrade all the `.sln`, `.csproj` etc files. I got the `devenv ... /upgrade` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/27625352/492