# Get Access to Microsoft Azure Inside Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, azure, visual-studio-2013

I have a windows phone application build for windows phone 8, in Visual Studio 2012. I have started incorporating azure, and found that Visual Studio 2013, was a smarter choice for this. Therefore I installed the new VS, and opened the file, but I cannot get it to upgrade the solution.

I use the Visual Studio Version Selector as default opener, and it open the solution in my VS2013. But it is still VS2012 version, as can be seen on the picture:
[image: Overview of solution]

I have tried to use Save as, which is stated as a solution [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688250/how-can-you-batch-upgrade-solution-files-to-open-in-visual-studio-2013) But still the solution does not change. Anyone has a suggestion for how to upgrade the solution to VS2013?

What I want to use is what is shown in this video on [Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Azure-Mobile-Services-Tools-in-Visual-Studio-2013). So I need to some how upgrade my project, or do I have to copy the code to a new project :-/ ?

I tried installing the SDK's from [Microsoft Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/), but still no luck.

**EDIT**
The feature where you add connected service is not available for windows phone. And you do therefore not need to upgrade the VS solution. But still I had problems getting access to the server.

Go to "View", and click "Server Explorer". There one can see a windows/Azure logo, by clicking it you will add your windows azure account. apparently this does not mean adding your services even though it states that you are logged in and with the correct subscription.

**Solution**
However the solution I stumbled upon was to add a new Mobile Service. Where then get prompted to choose my subscription which then was not there. Apparently the subscriptions can be loaded in different ways. Therefore in this new popup under subscriptions choose import. And you basically get the route described.

After importing the subscription, you then cancel creating a new services(If you did not need it :)). And now all your azure stuff will be accessible to manage as seen in [this link](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Azure-Mobile-Services-Tools-in-Visual-Studio-2013).

However it does not create the code lines since you are not using "add connected services" which is possible in windows apps.

Finally an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot convert solution from Visual Studio 2012 to 2013 because it is not changed at all.
Sln is just xml file and it is remain same so there is no need to convert it from 2012 to 2013

Comment: Also, read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513306/how-to-force-a-solution-file-sln-to-be-opened-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: @RadenkoZec I saw this answer to, I want to be able to use the new features of Azure incorporation, but not able to do this. So you say I cannot leverage this feature without creating a new project?

Comment: No I am just saying you don't need to convert from VS2012 sln to VS2013 sln because file format is remained same. You just need to choose default program for handling sln files (VS2013) or open first VS2013 then inside VS2013 open that existing solution file

Comment: @RadenkoZec I am opening it in in VS2013. But my project/solution is not able to utilize the new feature for adding a reference to a mobile service. Or is this feature only for windows projects and not windows phone, that would contradict some information I have read.

Comment: I guess you probably need to install some toolkit for Azure.
Check here maybe :
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/developer-tools/

Comment: @RadenkoZec I have started using Azure, in VS2012, but this new feature in VS2013 enables me to code the server side locally and upload it. Instead of doing it in the browser. So I have the references in the project installed. But I still cannot do it.