# How to convert project from VS2012 to VS2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Funny question but I stacked on it. I opened in VS2013 solution file which uses VS2012, but it still doesn't show me any screen for upgrade solution to VS2013. I mean I can open this project in VS 2013 and it works but solution file still shows that it use VS2012

[image]

According to this article some wizard should be shown, but it doesn't
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms185327(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: You are linking to the article of Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Check also this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513306/how-to-force-a-solution-file-sln-to-be-opened-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: I've already found the answer. put it as answer below. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer. We need to correct manually the Visual Studio sln file like this

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2013
VisualStudioVersion = 12.0.21005.1
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
```

Answer (score 6):

Open the project using VS2013, then go the the directory that the project is in and change the
extension of the Solution file (*.sln) to something like *.sln_12. Now save the project and a new sln file will be created.

Answer (score 1):

Check this url http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/06/12/vs-2013-can-load-vs-2012-and-vs-2010-projects.aspx. It supports round-tripping with older versions of visual studio so it doesn't upgrade solution/project file automatically.

Comment: But then how to upgrade the project? How to run that wizard?