# Open all Projects with VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When i doubleclick a project in the file explorer i want always use VS2015.

I looked in the registry and the value of  **HKLM\Software\Microsft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\devenv.exe** is correctly  set to:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio **14.0**\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

(like described here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/568e32af-d724-4ac6-8e8f-72181c4320b3/set-default-version-of-visual-studio)

I assume there is somekind of version marker in the visual studio project,

Any hint on how to force to use 2015 (without uninstalling the old verison)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below lines from `*.sln` file specifies what version of VS IDE is used by default and the minimum IDE that you can use for this project

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2013
VisualStudioVersion = 12.0.21005.1
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
```

You can manually update the `VisualStudioVersion`, `Format Version` & the text in 2nd line `# Visual Studio xxxx` and have it opened in the IDE that you need

Comment: I've done that for my web solution, but it is still opened in VS2013 Community Edition when I double click the .sln file in the Explorer. Any thoughts why it happens?

Comment: Found an answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513306/how-to-force-a-solution-file-sln-to-be-opened-in-visual-studio-2013). Needed to do "Open with.." and associate .sln file with "Visual Studio Version Selector".