# Upgrade .NET web application from VS2010 TO 2013 did not change the icon to VS2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a web application which is built on VS2010. I am trying to upgrade it to 2013. I did open .sln file with VS2013. It open without error so i make few changes.

One thing i realize the icon of solution file still look VS2010. What i have to do so that .Sln file looks it is built on VS2013.

Thanks

Comment: Is it just the icon that's incorrect, or does the actual solution still open in VS2010 instead of 2013?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513306/how-to-force-a-solution-file-sln-to-be-opened-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: Brandon. It is just the icon of solution file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the Solution file (.SLN) file for your project and right click on it and open in notepad.

At the top of the file change:
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00

## Visual Studio 2010

To:

Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00

## Visual Studio 2013

Then the solution should open with VS2013.

More detailed info here:
[How to force a Solution file (SLN) to be opened in Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513306/how-to-force-a-solution-file-sln-to-be-opened-in-visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click and select "Open With" and then "Choose Default Program"
2. Select the check box "Always use the selected program to open this
   kind of file"
3. Click OK

Comment: Won't that open all .SLN files in VS2013 instead of just the one?

Comment: I have one .sln file. I did try as you said but still looks same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the icon displayed for an individual .sln file.

For all non .exe files, explorer displays the icon of the application associated with that file type (i.e. `.sln` extension).

Since explorer is currently showing your .sln files with a VS 2010 icon, then your machine is currently configured to associate .sln files with VS 2010.

If you change the default association of your .sln files to VS2013/VS2015/etc., then explorer will display the appropriate associated VS icon.

Comment: Can you help me out how to chage the default association.

Comment: Right-click a .sln file. Hit 'Properties'. At the top of the properties dialog, you should see 'Change...' button next to "Opens With" label. Hit it: Now select the version of VS you want to open solutions by default.