# "Unspecified error" trying to open VS2010 solution in VS2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a Visual Studio 2010 .sln file which I would like to convert to Visual Studio 2012. While this task should be fairly simple following for example [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12406912/3242721):

> I managed to 'convert' the solution file to change the line containing '# Visual Studio 2010' to '# Visual Studio 2012' in the .SLN file.

it started to produce "Unspecified error" every time I try to open such upgraded solution in Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating contents of the solution file in question I realized that the path to our TFS server has changed in the mean time while we haven't modified the .sln and that was causing the "Unspecified error". Parts of the .sln file that I had to modify:

```
Global
    ...
    GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
        ...
        SccTeamFoundationServer = http://<new_url>.com:8080/tfs/defaultcollection
        SccAuxPath22 = http://<new_url>.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
        ...
    EndGlobalSection
    ...
EndGlobal
```

Hope this will help somebody else in the future.