# Initializer list not working with vector in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++11 features in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421825/c11-features-in-visual-studio-2012)

So I was reading up on C++11 initializer lists today via [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Initializer_lists) and saw that C++11 supports the following syntax for the standard containers:

```
std::vector<std::string> v = { "xyzzy", "plugh", "abracadabra" };
std::vector<std::string> v({ "xyzzy", "plugh", "abracadabra" });
std::vector<std::string> v{ "xyzzy", "plugh", "abracadabra" };
```

When I try the following in Visual Studio 2012 I get the compilation error `C2552: 'vecs' : non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list`

Here is my code:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> vecs = {"h", "g", "e"};
}
```

Does VS2012 not support initializer lists or am I just misunderstanding something?

Thanks!

Comment: Yet it was much quicker for me to ask a question on SO than read some poorly laid out MSDN article.  I guess I shouldn't post to SO next time.

Comment: I agree with Polaris. MSDN angers me.

Comment: make sure you don't forget the commas... vector<string> x = {"one" "two"};  its a concatenation of two strings..

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 does not support initializer lists.

Well, it didn't until the November 2012 CTP. Now it does, at least in an alpha state. Granted, this code still won't work in it because they're still putting initializer lists into the standard library itself.

Comment: Thanks Nicol, here is a fairly good table describing the list of features VS2012 supports: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx

Comment: The support is atrocious though. `int main() { for (int i : {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}) { } }` gives an internal compiler error. [edit] actually, the pre-CTP one crashes. The CTP one just lacks the begin / end functions for initializer lists.

Comment: @dascandy: Yes. That's part of the lack of standard library support for initializer lists: not having proper overloads for std::begin and std::end, which ranged-based `for` relies on.

Comment: Hmm it's 2015 and VS 2012 still doesn't seem to support it..