# Reassigning const char array with unknown size

Tags: c++, c, arrays, char, constants

So i have this 2 arrays inside my main function:

```
const char* basket[];
const char* basket_peach[] = {"1 1111 2 0000","2 2222 2 0000", 0};
...
    if (strcmp (c_id,"somebasketid") == 0){
        basket = basket_peach;
    }
...
```

If i try to do this:

```
...
    if (strcmp (c_id,"somebasketid") == 0){
         const char* basket[] = basket_peach;
    }
...
```

My main function tell me this " error: use of undeclared identifier 'basket'"

Any good idea how to do this one ?

Comment: Enable all warnings for your compiler. Then study arrays and pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need room for `basket`

```
const char* basket[]; /* Array of pointers with 0 length */
const char* basket_peach[] = {"1 1111 2 0000","2 2222 2 0000", 0};
```

should be

```
const char *basket_peach[] = {"1 1111 2 0000","2 2222 2 0000", 0};
const char *basket[sizeof(basket_peach) / sizeof(basket_peach[0])];
```

---

```
basket = basket_peach;
```

you can't assign to an array in this way, use a loop:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(basket) / sizeof(basket[0]); i++) {
    basket[i] = basket_peach[i];
}
```

or declare `basket` as a pointer to pointer:

```
const char *basket_peach[] = {"1 1111 2 0000","2 2222 2 0000", 0};
const char **basket;
...
basket = basket_peach;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, you can't assign an array in C and C++.

Moreover, the following will not even compile:

```
const char* basket[];
```

Arrays must be declared with an explicit size (inside the `[]`) or an initializer list from which the compiler can deduce the size.

If you're writing C++, what you really need is a [**`vector`**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/):

```
std::vector<const char*> basket;
std::vector<const char*> basket_peach = {"1 1111 2 0000","2 2222 2 0000", 0};
...
    if (strcmp (c_id,"somebasketid") == 0){
        basket = basket_peach;
    }
```

The above will work as you expected. Better yet, replace `const char*` with [**`string`**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) as well:

```
std::vector<std::string> basket;
std::vector<std::string> basket_peach = {"1 1111 2 0000","2 2222 2 0000", ""};
...                                                          NOTICE THIS! ^^
    if (c_id == "somebasketid"){
        basket = basket_peach;
    }
```

This will also work as you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when trying your first solution , i can't assign a list .
non-aggregate type 'std::vector<const char *>' cannot be initialized with an
      initializer list

Comment: It should work. Did you include `<vector>`? Or are you using an old/non-conforming version of C++? Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16087886/3425536