# Vector initialization with more values in c++11

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++11, initializer-list

I am not sure why I get compile error for this code:

```
vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
```

We do use c++11. Is it possible that somehow the vector files .h and .cpp are not updated?
How do I check that?

The error I get is: "initialization with {} is not allowed ..."

Comment: Are you compiling with `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x`?

Comment: I am working in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Oh, that's it then. List initialization is not supported.

Comment: P.S.: See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx): `Initializer lists -> no`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initializer list not working with vector in Visual Studio 2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654394/initializer-list-not-working-with-vector-in-visual-studio-2012)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2012 does not support initializer lists.

Check out this summary for details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx