# vector<string> initialization with {...} is not allowed in VS2012?

Tags: c++, string, vector

I was wondering how I can initialize a `std::vector` of strings, without having to use a bunch of `push_back`'s in *Visual Studio Ultimate 2012*.

---

I've tried `vector<string> test = {"hello", "world"}`, but that gave me the following error:

> `Error: initialization with '{...}' is not allowed for an object of type "std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string>>`

---

- Why do I receive the error?
- Any ideas on what I can do to store the strings?

Comment: Upgrade your compiler to a version that supports C++11

Comment: What @Brian [said](http://ideone.com/DUg34e)

Comment: VS2012 doesn't support list initialization. The Nov CTP version does, but it still doesn't provide the appropriate constructors for the standard library types. So you'll have to upgrade to VS2013.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The problem**

You'll have to upgrade to a more recent compiler version (and standard library implementation), if you'd like to use what you have in your snippet.

*VS2012* [doesn't support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) `std::initializer_list`, which means that the overload among `std::vector`'s constructors, that you are trying to use, simply doesn't exist.

In other words; the example cannot be compiled with *VS2012*.

- [**msdn.com** - Support For C++11 Features (Modern C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx)

---

**Potential Workaround**

Use an intermediate *array* to store the `std::string`s, and use that to initialize the vector.

```
std::string const init_data[] = {
  "hello", "world"
};

std::vector<std::string> test (std::begin (init_data), std::end (init_data));
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Why do I receive the error?**
Visual Studio 2012 doesn't support list initialization before the [2012 November update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2797915/description-of-visual-studio-2012-update-1) according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654394/initializer-list-not-working-with-vector-in-visual-studio-2012).

**2.Any ideas on what I can do to store the strings?**

Using push_back() is a totally valid solution. Example:

```cpp
#include<vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<string> test;
    test.push_back("hello");
    test.push_back("world");
    for(int i=0; i<test.size(); i++)
     cout<<test[i]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```