# Init the map of structs with string key

Tags: c++, dictionary, static, struct, init

I have a

```
struct OpDesc {
        std::string  OPName;
        size_t       OPArgsMin;
        bool         IsVaribaleArgsNum;
        bool         IsOPChange;
        std::string  ChangeNodeOP;
        std::string  ChangeNodeLabel;
        bool         IsOPDelete;
        const char*  ErrMsg;
    };
```

And want to init a `std::map<string, OpDesc>`.

I tried doing it this way :

```
typedef std::map<std::string,struct OpDesc> OpDescMap;
OpDescMap opDesc;
opDesc["StoreOp"] = {"StoreOp",2,false,false,"","",false,""};
/// etc.
```

I can't compile that with VS10. I get : `error C2059: syntax error : '{'`

How can it be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is valid C++11 (see [Uniform Initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization)), however, VS10 does not support it. It was only added to VS12 (see [C++ features in VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421825/c11-features-in-visual-studio-2012)). One option is to upgrade your compiler to one that has better conformance to C++11.

If you can't upgrade, you'll have to fallback to C++03 syntax. You can either use an intermediate variable:

```
OpDesc op = {"StoreOp", 2, false, false, "", "", false, ""};
opDesc[op.OPName] = op;
```

Or add a constructor to your structure:

```
struct OpDesc {
   // ... all fields
   OpDesc(std::string const& opName, size_t opArgsMin, bool isVariableArgsNum,
          bool isOpChange, std::string const& changeNameOp,
          std::string const& changeNodeLabel, bool isOpDelete,
          char const* errMsg)
   : OPName(opName), OPArgsMin(opArgsMin), IsVariableArgsNum(isVariableArgsNum),
     IsOpChange(isOpChange), ChangeNameOp(changeNameOp),
     ChangeNodeLabel(changeNodeLabel), IsOpDelete(isOpDelete),
     ErrMsg(errMsg) {}
};

opDesc["StoreOp"] = OpDesc("StoreOp", 2, false, false, "", "", false, "");
```

Comment: The syntax is the one the OP used: this is a limitation of VC10.

Comment: @AndyProwl Thank you, I've updated my answer to list this is an incompatibility of VS10.

Answer (score 1):

Could work around by creating a cosntructor for `OpDesc`

```
OpDesc(const std::string&  oPName="StoreOp",
      size_t oPArgsMin = 0,
      bool  isVaribaleArgsNum = false,
      bool  isOPChange=false,
      const std::string&  changeNodeOP = "",
      const std::string&  changeNodeLabel = "",
      bool  isOPDelete = false,
      const char*  errMsg= "" )
  :OPName(oPName),
  OPArgsMin(oPArgsMin),
  IsVaribaleArgsNum(isVaribaleArgsNum),
  IsOPChange(isOPChange),
  ChangeNodeOP(changeNodeOP),
  ChangeNodeLabel(changeNodeLabel),
  IsOPDelete(isOPDelete),
  ErrMsg(errMsg)
{
}

OpDescMap opDesc;
opDesc["StoreOp"] = OpDesc("StoreOp", 2, false, false, "", "", false, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @billz's solution is to construct the object and insert it into the map in two separate steps:

```
OpDesc od = { "StoreOp",2,false,false,"","",false,"" };
opDesc["StoreOp"] = od;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another compiler: Your source code works with clang++ V 3.3 and gcc 4.7.2.