# C++11 DirectX Math: XMVECTORF32 as base structure initialization

Tags: c++, math, c++11, initialization, directx

I'm writing another game engine in C++11/VC11 which presently uses DirectX/Direct3D11 as rendering backend. In order to hide DirectX types from the public interface (and a possible later implementation of an OpenGL backend), I'm rolling a linear algebra library on my own, which - however - still uses DirectX Math internally for the time being. DirectX Math is more or less a bunch of typedefs around the C++ SIMD intrinsics (__m128 etc.).
In order to keep the levels of indirection low and have the stuff as "atomic" and inlined as possible, I prefer to inherit from the DirectX Math types directly (XMVECTORF32 in this case) - i.e. I don't want to use it as a member variable:

```
struct vector4 : private DirectX::XMVECTORF32
```

MSDN gives following example for the correct initialization of the XMVECTORF32 structure:

```
XMVECTOR data;
XMVECTORF32 floatingVector = { 0.f, 0.f, 0.1f, 1.f };
data = floatingVector;
```

However, my attempts to initialize the XMVECTORF32 as a base structure are not understood by the compiler.

```
struct vector4 : private DirectX::XMVECTORF32 // not XMFLOAT4 due to possible conversation overhead
{
    friend class matrix44;

    inline vector4(scalar v0, scalar v1, scalar v2, scalar v3)
        :   DirectX::XMVECTORF32{v0, v1, v2, v3} // ERROR: ';' expected
    {
    }
};
```

Am I missing something? How to correctly perform the base initialization I am intending to do? Is there maybe some new C++11 initialization sugar to help me out?

------------ **EDIT** -----------

For some reasons, I was not seeing the obvious. After examining the definition of XMVECTORF32, it was clear that the underlying union-float-array "f" was accessible for me, so the initialization looks like this.

```
struct vector4 : private DirectX::XMVECTORF32
{
    friend struct matrix44;

    inline vector4(scalar v0, scalar v1, scalar v2, scalar v3)
    {
        f[0] = v0;
        f[1] = v1;
        f[2] = v2;
        f[3] = v3;
    }
};
```

No casts, no unions, no c arrays. With inlining, performance should be near optimum.

------------ **EDIT 2** -----------

XMVECTORF32 is not meant for **storing** data. Therefore the vector must inherit from XMFLOAT4. Otherwise, this gives non-reproducible access violation exceptions, especially with optimizations turned on. Here is more background: http://www.asawicki.info/news_1429_xna_math_and_access_violation.html

My final code looks like this:

```
struct vector4 : private DirectX::XMFLOAT4
{
    friend struct matrix44;

    inline vector4(scalar v0, scalar v1, scalar v2, scalar v3)
        :   DirectX::XMFLOAT4(v0, v1, v2, v3)
    {
    }

    inline scalar& v0() { return x; }
    inline scalar& v1() { return y; }
    inline scalar& v2() { return z; }
    inline scalar& v3() { return w; }
};
```

The vector data must be loaded into an XMVECTOR using XMLoadFloat4 prior SIMD calculations - no way around it. Think of XMVECTOR like a register - not a memory location.

Comment: What version of the VC compiler are you using?

Comment: Have you tried GLM? It has GL in its name, but it should work just fine with DX.

Comment: @AndyProwl Visual Studio Express 2012 Version 11.0.51106.01 Update 1

Comment: @Cubic Thanks, but I try to limit the use of external libraries as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that `DirectX::XMVECTORF32` is an aggregate class, your code is fine in C++11 (see a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3FDYza$56) which demonstrates its use).

However, the compiler you are using does **not** support uniform initialization (as clarified by **[this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421825/c11-features-in-visual-studio-2012)** on StackOverflow), and in C++03 you cannot initialize a base aggregate class as you would copy-initialize a variable.

Therefore, you will have to initialize the member of your base class explicitly in the initialization list, or call something like `SetVector()` in the body of your `vector4` constructor.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Working with C++11 in GCC was way better, but I'm stuck with MSVC due to this new "metro app" thing and windows store requirements.

Final solution:
  inline vector4(scalar v0, scalar v1, scalar v2, scalar v3)
  {
   f[0] = v0;
   f[1] = v1;
   f[2] = v2;
   f[3] = v3;
  }