# Why doesn't VS2012 recognize certain C++11 keywords in a C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++11

On http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword, I found a list of C++11 keywords, however some of those VS2012 didn't recognize in a C++ project.

They keywords which VS didn't identify are: alignas, alignof, constexpr, noexcept, and thread_local.

Microsoft's Visual Studio website says that VS2012 implements C++11, so I'm wondering why it didn't recognize those keywords. Neither did VS recognize bitor, and others which aren't even new to C++11. So is there a specific reason why VS doesn't recognize these keywords, or is there some setting that I need to change? I have all the updates, so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: just because vs2012 implements most of the c++11 standard doesn't mean it supports all of it

Comment: Ok because on the website, it said that VS2012 implemented C++11, so I took that to mean it implemented all of it. And out of curiosity, why wouldn't they implement all of it. For a high-end IDE, it seems like a logical thing to do.

Comment: What website? Here is the [official list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx). Look at all the `No`s. Note that there should be some new announcements about C++11 support during or after the Build conference (June 26-28).

Comment: Honestly it's a lot of work clang and gcc only recently finished full support of c++11, c++ is one of the most complex languages so it is not easy to write a compiler for it

Comment: @JesseGood. Got it. I didn't scroll down

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421825/c11-features-in-visual-studio-2012

Comment: @Yakk which most are you referring to

Comment: @aaronman The only most you typed in these comments -- most of the C++11 standard that vs2012 supports...  I would eyeball it at less than half of the standard if you don't count alpha releases.

Comment: @Yakk I agree with you but there were two mosts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Support of C++11 in VS 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx) as you see is incomplete. The keyword list you provide looks like matching the unimplemented stuff.