# C++ Unable to use vector<string> as return type

Tags: c++, string, vector, return-type

I am trying to use the functions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/586606) to split a string by a deliminator, but I am getting a handful of errors whenever I try to use `vector<string>` as a return type.

I made a simple function that returns a `vector<string>` as a test, but am still getting the same errors:

```
// Test.h
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <string>

    using namespace std;
using namespace System;

namespace Test
{
    vector<string> TestFunction(string one, string two);
}
```

.

```
//Test.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Test.h"

namespace Test
{
    vector<string> TestFunction(string one, string two) {
        vector<string> thing(one, two);
        return thing;
    }
}
```

And a screenshot of the errors:
[image: Errors]

Does anyone know why I seem to be unable to use `vector<string>` as a return type?

Comment: your return type will have to be `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: @e.James both `string` and `vector` are in the `std` namespace, right? SO shouldn't `using namespace std;` take care of that?

Comment: Aside: it's generally considered very bad practice to have a `using` inside a .h file.  Especially one that references namespaces vs. types

Comment: `vector<string> thing(one, two);` this doesn't initialize vector with two strings, there is no such constructor.

Comment: @WilHall: yes, my bad. I didn't realize that there was a `using` directive in the header. Scary!

Comment: +1 for creating a small (but, alas, not *minimal*), complete sample program. http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not a valid [`vector<string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) constructor:

```
vector<string> thing(one, two);
```

Change to (for example):

```
std::vector<std::string> TestFunction(std::string one, std::string two) {
    std::vector<std::string> thing;

    thing.push_back(one);
    thing.push_back(two);

    return thing;
}
```

Also consider changing parameters to be `const std::string&` to avoid unnecessary copy.

Comment: This seems to have fixed it, though, I'd like to be able to use the list syntax, as per your link, i.e: `vector<string> thing {one, two};` - but that is failing, see: http://cl.ly/3m2O1E0e3X2L2y1y0036

Comment: You'll need to enabled C++11 features to enable that syntax, if your compiler supports it.

Comment: @WilHall According to [this table](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport), only gcc already supports initializer lists (and clang++ in its svn repository, if you follow the link) .

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010 - though this question suggests initializer lists aren't supported D: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121529/how-to-enable-c0x-features-in-visual-studio-initializer-lists-support

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with the return type but with the call to the constructor. The compiler is picking the `std::vector` constructor:

```
template <typename InputIterator>
vector( InputIterator b, InputIterator e );
```

as the best candidate, which it is according to the standard, by substituting `std::string` as the `InputIterator` parameter. Your compiler seems to be using traits internally to verify that the argument actually complies with the requirements of `InputIterator` and complaining because `std::string` does not fulfill those requirements.

The simple solution is to change the code in the function to:

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
v.push_back( one );
v.push_back( two );
return v;
```

Answer (score 1):

the string type is actually a member of the `std::` namespace. The proper return type for your function will be `std::vector<std::string>`.

You are able to avoid using the `std::` prefix in your CPP file because of the line `using namespace std;`, but in your header, you *must* include the `std::` prefix.

Whatever you do, do **not** place the `using namespace std;` in the header file.