# What is vs2012 cl.exe equivalent to gcc -std=c++11?

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, visual-studio-2012, c++11, cl.exe

Is there a command line option I can pass to VS2012 or VS2013 cl.exe to specify if I want to use C++11 or C++98 syntax? Like GCC's -std=c++11 option.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. VS always recognizes C++11 syntax; well, the parts it supports, at least.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you might want to post that as an answer since it seems to be what the user was looking for..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable C++0x features in Visual studio? \[Initializer Lists support\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121529/how-to-enable-c0x-features-in-visual-studio-initializer-lists-support)

Answer (score 1):

Quoting Igor Tandetnik from the comments:

> Not to my knowledge. VS always recognizes C++11 syntax; well, the parts it supports, at least.

Posted answer as community wiki so that this question no longer remains unanswered.