# Qt build fails due to missing std::isnan in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, c++11, compiler-errors

I'm trying to build Qt 5.2.0 from source using Visual Studio 2012. It is failing while compiling the following file:

`/qtdeclarative/src/qml/jsruntime/qv4value_p.h`

With the following error:

`191: error C2039: _isnan: is not a member of std`

Line 191 contains the following:

`return doubleValue() && !std::isnan(doubleValue());`

[According to cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan), `std::isnan` should be defined in the header `cmath`, since C++11. The Qt header file does include this header. When I inspect `cmath` in Visual Studio, I cannot see a function named `isnan`.

Am I right in concluding that VS2012 is missing this C++11 function? At first I thought I might have to enable C++11 support somehow, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5121547/1227469) C++11 support is enabled by default. Given that [binary downloads for Qt are available for VS2010 and VS2012](http://qt-project.org/downloads), clearly it is possible to build with the respective compilers. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: What are your Qt configure options? Can you try building 5.2.1? What puzzles me is that a VS2012 build is amongst the continuous integration builds of Qt http://qt-project.org/wiki/CI_Configurations http://testresults.qt-project.org/ci/QtDeclarative_stable_Integration/latest-success/

Answer (score 1):

`isnan` was implemented in Visual Studio'sstandard library starting with Visual Studio 2013.

There's most likely some sort of define to tell it that you don't have `std::isnan` available.

Comment: I would try `#ifdef isnan` as a check, if function is not defined then this symbol should be available as a macro (macro explains error message).

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try passing -no-c++11 to Qt's configure tool and see if that works. If not, I will check the defines as you suggested.

Comment: I just glanced at the code and there's no way this will compile with VS2010 or 2012. My guess is that this module isn't included.